# I want to pose a puzzle, but I don't really know enough to make it as detailed as it needs to be

Tags: discussion

I'm curious if anyone can calculate the maximum possible number of "living" cells on a given grid size for Conway's Game Of Life.

I would have no way of knowing how to define winning criteria or develop test cases.

I saw something about "the sandbox", but can't find any details.
Any suggestions or should I just forget about it? I don't even care if someone takes the idea and posts it right now. :)

Comment: If you're looking at this page on a desktop computer, you should see a link to the sandbox in a box to the right, under the heading *Featured on meta*.

Comment: Thanks! I had looked for tags and other links, but I didn't expect it to be a post.

Comment: For future reference, [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) is a link for the sandbox.